# How to make a dynamic header import in qml(import QtQuick 1.0 or import QtQuick 2.0)?

Tags: dynamic, import, qml

I need to make a dynamic header import in qml. Is this possible?

```
if(y = x)
   import QtQuick 1.0
else
   import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
 ....
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in QML. You could use Qt.createComponent and create the QML string dynamically

Comment: I will make this...Thanks =D